# C++ pointer spoofing

Tags: c++11, pointers, boost, smart-pointers, option-type

I am currently working on a piece of code in which lots of pointers are used without proper ownership control. In some cases, it becomes a huge contraint because everything has to be initialized properly and can't be changed afterwards. So far I have been using dummy wrappers

```
// MyObject.h
struct MyObject
{
    virtual int myMethod(int i){ return i; }
};
struct MyObjectWrapper : MyObject
{
     MyObject *obj = nullptr;
     int myMethod(int i){ if(obj) return obj->myMethod(i); }
     void setObject(MyObject *obj){ this->obj = obj; }
}

// MyObjectFactory.h
MyObject *createMyObject(){
    MyObject *object = new MyObject();
    MyObjectWrapper *wrapper = new MyObjectWrapper();
    wrapper->setObject(object);
    return wrapper;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do pointer "spoofing" by returning an object that is not actually a pointer but has the type of one, so that I can return a smart pointer instead of the regular pointer without changing the rest of the code. Is there a way of achieving that?

Additionnally, this led me to think about boost::optional. How is it implemented? Is boost using a lot of preprocessing for reflection? I cannot understand how it is possible to "intercept" a method call on a variable without neither knowing the name of the method nor using heavy preprocessing.

In case the answers are simple NOs, are you aware of any design pattern that can be used to work around my issues?

Comment: What stops you from using a regular smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` and pass `pointer.get()` to the function?

Comment: @nwp unique_ptr::get returns a raw pointer abd this is what I am trying to avoid. Because if this raw pointer is stored somewhere, there is not way to change the object afterwards. Returning a smart pointer would be good, but I would have to refactor many classes and the backward compatibility would not be preserved.

Comment: I did not understand well the question (or the problem). Where do you want to return the "fake" pointer to be used? You want to use the "fake pointer" inside `MyObjectWrapper` ?

Comment: @Gonmator Imagine that the rest of the code uses a factory to get instances of MyObject. Then they store the resulting pointer. And if I want to change this instance afterwards, the stored pointer will be damgling. So far I use a MyObjectWrapper that inherits from MyObject (it's not clear in my example, I will complete it), and return a wrapper from the factory.

Comment: @user7205445 When you typed `return obj.myMethod(i);`, did you mean `return obj->myMethod(i);`?

Comment: You can use a pointer to the pointer, but its not good practice. You should be able to update the objects that have the dangling pointer with the new pointer. Rebasing your code now is better than waiting until you are forced to rebase due to new features

Comment: Note that `myMethod` in `MyObjectWrapper` doesn't work if `obj` is null -- it fails to return a value, which results rapidly in UB.

Comment: @Flynsee Are you sure your workaround works as you expect? Because `MyObject::myMethod` is not virtual and `createMyObject()` returns a pointer to `MyObject`, when the client invokes `myMethod()`, it will call the method in the base class, not in the derived (wrapper).

Comment: @Gonmator This is not an actual part of my code. Just a small example of how I want it to behave, written in a hurry through a smartphone.

Comment: "I cannot understand how it is possible to "intercept" a method call" -- boost::optional overloads operators * and -> . This is the same thing that smart pointers do: operator takes `optional<T>` as input and returns a pointer or a reference to `T`.

Comment: @Andzrej Thank you. I never actually used it and I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Ya know. It's time for the "Don't Defend Against Macchiavelli¹" talk. You'll **always** be able to know the address of an object if you have access to the object.

If you don't trust your users for that, don't give them access.

This is why the e.g. the OS kernel gives out opaque handles (aside from technical reasons).

In case your question was "Can I automatically create a proxy object" the answer is NO:

- not without code generation tools
- not without overloadable `operator.` (which doesn't currently exist outside of language proposals)

¹ e.g. http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm

Comment: It's not really about trust. I want to use smart pointers, but I don't want to refactor all the code - and I cannot anyway. As you see, the dummy wrapper I wrote does the job. But it is heavy and I feel like I could do better.

Comment: It's not heavy. If you do it in a header, everything inlines away. If not, LTO can do that too. I think you're just looking for the automation step to generate the code. It's something that you'll have to make - there's no c++ language feature for it.

Comment: The dummy object actually doesn't do the job. The conversion `MyObjectWrapper *` => `MyObject*` is available. So, if you have `void foo(MyObject* ptr) { ptr->myMethod(5); }`, then this will NOT call `MyObjectWrapper::myMethod`

Comment: @MSalters good point actually. I didn't even look at the quality of the "wrapper". It's funny that it inherits *as well as* aggregates. The point is, transparent proxies cannot be had "for free". And if they're truly transparent, that means the address can be taken/stored, again.

Comment: @MSalters I edited MyObject::myMethod to a virtual one, it will make my question clearer. This was just a piece of code written in a minute, so it wasn't perfect indeed.

Comment: @sehe The wrapper inheriting from the object is exactly where lies my question. Basically what I am asking is whether there is a way to have this kind of wrapper but in a template fashion for instance: Wrapper<class T> : T, such that for any method Wrapper<T>::method returns T::method. Sorry my question wasn.t very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You want a type that can store a dumb pointer or a smart pointer relatively transparently?  Well, this isn't a good plan, but it can be done:

```
namespace details {
    template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply:std::false_type {};
    template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;

template<class T>
using dot_get_r = decltype( std::declval<T>().get() );
template<class T>
using can_get = can_apply< dot_get_r, T >;

template<class T>
struct ptr_like {
  T* get()const{
    if (!pvtable && !pimpl) return nullptr;
    return pvtable->get(pimpl.get());
  }
  explicit operator bool() const{ return !!get(); }

  // wall of == <= etc:
  friend bool operator==( ptr_like const& ptr, std::nullptr_t ) { return !(bool)ptr; }
  friend bool operator==( std::nullptr_t, ptr_like const& ptr ) { return !(bool)ptr; }
  friend bool operator!=( ptr_like const& ptr, std::nullptr_t ) { return (bool)ptr; }
  friend bool operator!=( std::nullptr_t, ptr_like const& ptr ) { return (bool)ptr; }

  friend bool operator==( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) {return lhs.get()==rhs.get();}
  friend bool operator!=( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) {return lhs.get()!=rhs.get();}
  friend bool operator<=( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) {return lhs.get()<=rhs.get();}
  friend bool operator>=( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) {return lhs.get()>=rhs.get();}
  friend bool operator<( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) {return lhs.get()<rhs.get();}
  friend bool operator>( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) {return lhs.get()>rhs.get();}

  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator==( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like<U> const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()==rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator==( ptr_like<U> const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()==rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator!=( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like<U> const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()!=rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator!=( ptr_like<U> const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()!=rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator<=( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like<U> const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()<=rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator<=( ptr_like<U> const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()<=rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator>=( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like<U> const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()>=rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator>=( ptr_like<U> const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()>=rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator<( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like<U> const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()<rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator<( ptr_like<U> const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()<rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator>( ptr_like const& lhs, ptr_like<U> const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()>rhs.get(); }
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<U*, T*>{}, int > =0
  >
  friend bool operator>( ptr_like<U> const& lhs, ptr_like const& rhs ) { return lhs.get()>rhs.get(); }

  // -> and unary * support:
  T* operator->()const{ return get(); }
  T& operator*()const{ return *get(); }

  // move:
  ptr_like(ptr_like&&)=default;
  ptr_like& operator=(ptr_like&&)=default;

  // copy:
  ptr_like(ptr_like const& o):
    pvtable(o.pvtable),
    pimpl(o.clone())
  {}

  ptr_like& operator=(ptr_like const& o) {
    auto tmp = o;
    swap(*this, tmp);
    return *this;
  }

  // swap:
  friend void swap( ptr_like& lhs, ptr_like& rhs ) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.vtable, rhs.vtable);
    swap(lhs.pimpl, rhs.pimpl);
  }

  // Construct from smart pointer:
  template<class Smart,
    class dSmart = std::decay_t<Smart>,
    std::enable_if_t< can_get<dSmart const&>{} && !std::is_same<dSmart, ptr_like>{}, int > =0
  >
  ptr_like( Smart&& smart ):
    pvtable( smart_vtable<dSmart>() ),
    pimpl( unique_ptr_with_deleter(std::forward<Smart>(smart)) )
  {}
  // construct from dumb pointer:
  template<class Dumb>
  ptr_like( Dumb* dumb ):
    pvtable( pointer_vtable<Dumb>() ),
    pimpl( unique_ptr_with_deleter(dumb) )
  {}
private:
  using state = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>;
  struct vtable {
    T* (*get)(void*) = 0;
    state (*clone)(state const&) = 0;
  };
  vtable const* pvtable = nullptr;
  state pimpl;

  state clone() const {
    if (!pimpl||!pvtable) return {nullptr, [](void*){}};
    return pvtable->clone( pimpl );
  }
  template<class U,
    class dU = std::decay_t<U>
  >
  static state unique_ptr_with_deleter(U&& u) {
    std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> r
    = {
      new dU(std::forward<U>(u)),
      [](void* ptr){
        delete static_cast<dU*>(ptr);
      }
    };
    return r;
  }
  template<class U>
  static vtable const* pointer_vtable() {
    static vtable const table = make_ptr_vtable<U>();
    return &table;
  }
  template<class O>
  static vtable const* smart_vtable() {
    static vtable const table = make_smart_vtable<O>();
    return &table;
  }
  template<class U>
  static vtable make_ptr_vtable() {
    return {
      [](void* ptr)->T*{
        return *static_cast<U**>(ptr);
      },
      [](state const& ptr)->state{
        return {ptr.get(), ptr.get_deleter()};
      }
    };
  }
  template<class O>
  static vtable make_smart_vtable() {
    return {
      [](void* ptr)->T*{
        O* o = static_cast<O*>(ptr);
        return o?o->get():nullptr;
      },
      [](state const& ptr)->state{
        O* o = static_cast<O*>(ptr.get());
        if (!o) return {nullptr, ptr.get_deleter()};
        return {new O(*o), ptr.get_deleter()};
      }
    };
  }    
};
```

note that `unique_ptr` does not qualify, as it cannot be copied while dumb pointers can.  Custom smart pointers (that can be copied) can be used.  We could extend this to having it throw/terminate if you pass it a non-copyable smart pointer and that value is copied instead of moved, if you where even more insane than this answer.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d934678f0a48ab4d).  Code is C++1z, and no I'm not making it C++11 or 14, it is a dumb idea to start with.

Code is incomplete -- `nullptr < p` doesn't work, for example.  Code is less than perfectly efficient (I could store dumb pointers more efficiently, and use SBO even for smart pointers).  Needs `std::less` specialization or have `<` use it.

But it is a proof of concept.

```
int foo( ptr_like<int> ptr ) {
  if (!ptr) return -1;
  return *ptr+1;
}
```

will compile.  The `ptr_like<int>` could be an `int*` or a `std::shared_ptr<int>` it won't care.  You can persist the `ptr_like<int>` and copy it around.  Copies of `shared_ptr<int>`s will maintain reference counts, copies of `int*` won't.

If you use this, you'll end up with a code base that is harder to maintain, not easier, as object lifetime will get more confusing, not less.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `ptr_like<T> p; T* raw = std::addressof(*p);` is still available

Comment: @sehe Sure, `*p` returns a `T&`.  `ptr_like<T>` is in no way safer than alternatives, it will not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.  If anything, it will aim your gun downward, modify the trigger to be vibration sensitive, and start tickling you.  It is just a type-erasure of pointer-like behavior.  However, it is the closest I can get to what the OP asked for; the ability to interchangably use raw pointers and smart pointers in some code.

Comment: @Yakk This is way above my c++ level. I have tried reading it but I need more time to understand it fully. I can't tell yet whether it answers my question, but it is definitely going to teach me a lot and I am already thankful for that.

Comment: @fly again, I was answering your question (as best it can be) while saying you the answer is your approach is wrong.  When I find a question whose simple answer is "no that is not possible in C++, and why would you do that anyway?" I sometimes produce a "solution" as an excercise; as practice.  The implementation is simply to demonstrate that it *could* be done, which then helps you see how bad it is to do it.  Saying "that is impossible and a bad idea" is in some sense weaker than "it is possible, but a bad idea".